# Logstash pull server date as config variable

Tags: logstash

As part of my logstash config I want to pull the current date from the server, which it uses as part of it's API query using http_poller.

Is there any way to do that? I've tried something along the lines of this:

```
$(date +%d%m%y%H%M%S)
```

But it doesn't get picked up. This is the config:

```
input{
 http_poller {
#proxy => { host => "" }
 proxy => ""
 urls => {
 q1 => {
 method => post
 url => ""
 headers => {.... }
 body => '{
 "rsid": "....",
 "globalFilters": [
 {
 "type": "dateRange",
 "dateRange": "%{+ddMMyyHHmmss}"
 }
 ................
 }'
 }
 }
 request_timeout => 60
 # Supports "cron", "every", "at" and "in" schedules by rufus scheduler
 schedule => { cron => "* * * * * UTC"}
 codec => "json"
 metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
 }
 }
 output {
 elasticsearch {
 hosts => ["xxxx"]
 index => "xxxx"
 }
 }
```

Comment: What is your config and what are you trying to do? In logstash you can use the local date on the server with something like `%{+ddMMyyHHmmss}` in your example.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thank you for the reply. I have used that code within the body tag of my logstash config and it doesnt resolve, it just prints it exactly how you have

Comment: Can you update your question with your config?

Comment: @leandrojmp Yes indeed added

Comment: Oh, I see now what you are trying to do, it won't work this way with the http_poller filter. I think that there is an github issue to deal with that, but it is still open: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-http_poller/issues/51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like a variable declaration we can do in input .. 
a workaround rather is to define env variables with dates eg. on windows (powershell script) -

```bsh
$env:startDate=(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$env:endDate=(Get-Date).AddDays(0).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Then we can use these variables as ${startDate}  in the url .
However once logstash is started the dates remain static. 
Guess we need to restart logstash script everyday for it to take the new value of date.

Another alternative is to write a proxy webservice, which will probably be in java or other languages , where the java class can be declared with variables and  then it invokes the actual webservice and returns the response back to the logstash script.

This issue is pending in logstash since 2016... not sure why it cannot be addressed !